# Unintentional model duplicates created in Pose Mode

Tags: animation, rigging, pose-mode

I am working on a tutorial for Blender involving modeling a low-poly character model, but when I try moving the arms or head around in Pose Mode, the ears of the model create unintentional duplicates of themselves, and it's very annoying to see. What do I do? If you rotate the left arm in Pose Mode regularly, a duplicate of the right ear moves out of place, and vice versa.

Here is the tutorial I am working on, though I'm working on a fireman instead of a police officer.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yjjLD3h3yRc&t=191s

Here is a screenshot of the problem I am talking about...

[image]

And here is the downloadable file of the project I am working on from my Cloud account...

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I can't see the duplicated ears you're talking about in the file you share

Comment: This is what I'm talking about.

Comment: Whenever you rotate the arms with regular rotation in Pose Mode, you'll see a duplicate of the ear move with it. If you move the left arm, the right ear is moved, and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

In the *Object Properties* you can set *Viewport Display > Display As* to `Bounds`. When you do this for the mesh object after you've selected it you will see a large box. That's your model displayed as a box. And yes, it's way too large:

[image: screenshot of the box]

Reset the setting to `Textured` again. Then zoom out and you will see the problem:

[image: screenshot of model]

The fix is easy. Select the model's mesh, go to *Edit* mode and delete the "extra ears".

Comment: Where do I find "Object Properties"?

Comment: It's the tab that is selected in the screenshot on the right (orange "square" icon above the blue "wrench" icon) in the properties sidebar. To see the Viewport Display section you need to scroll down a bit. If you hover the icons a tooltip displays the name of the icon.

Comment: Where do I find the icons?

Comment: It's one of the icons that are arranged vertically on the right side. I've added a screenshot to the answer. (1) is the *Object Properties* tab and there (2) is the *Viewport Display* section where you can activate the box model.